# How does the Perl 'use' syntax work?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Sample code:

> `m1.pm`

```
my $a;
my $b;
sub init {
    $a = shift;
    $b = shift;
}

sub printab {
    print "a = -$a-\n";
    print "b = -$b-\n";
}

1;
```

> `m2.pm`

```
my $a;
my $b;
sub init {
    $a = shift;
    $b = shift;
}

1;
```

> `test.pl`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use m1;
use m2;

init('hello', 'world');
printab();
```

Run:

```
$ perl test.pl
a = --
b = --
$
```

What happens is that the `init('hello', 'world')` call is mapped to `m2.pm` and initializes the variables (`$a` and `$b`) there.

This kind of makes sense, but what I do not understand is why those values are not available in `test.pl`.

- Is there something fundamentally wrong that I am trying to do here? **What is the correct way to use two modules with same named subroutines and variables?**
- How exactly does a Perl `use` work? It would help if someone could contrast it with C's `#include` directive.

Comment: For why I need this, please see [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144351/where-should-i-put-code-that-is-common-to-two-perl-modules/4144398#4144398).

Comment: Is this your complete code?  Do either of your modules define an `import` routine or inherit from `Exporter`.  If not, you aren't exporting the subroutines into `test.pl`

Comment: @Eric: yes, this is all.

Comment: Ok, see my answer for why it is not working.

Comment: Because m1 and m2 say they're *theirs*, and that other scopes should keep their mitts off of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, do read [perldoc perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html).

You do not declare a namespace in either module, so everything is in the `main` namespace. Declare `package m1;` in `m1.pm` and `package m2;` in `m2.pm`.

At the very least, you should implement an `import` method (or inherit the one `Exporter` provides) so that programs that use modules can decide what to import from where.

It also seems to me that you are exploring around the edges of OO.

Further:

- Avoid using `$a` and `$b` as variable names because it is easy to confuse them with the package variables `$a` and `$b` used by `sort`.
- Don't use lower case module names: They are reserved for pragmata.

A minimal implementation (all in one file for testing convenience) looks like this:

```
package My::M1;

use strict; use warnings;

sub new { my $class = shift; bless { @_ } => $class }

sub a {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($v) = @_;
    $self->{a} = $v if @_;
    return $self->{a};
}

sub b {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($v) = @_;
    $self->{b} = $v if @_;
    return $self->{b};
}

package My::M2;

use strict; use warnings;
use base 'My::M1';

sub printtab {
    my $self = shift;
    for my $x (qw(a b)) {
        printf "%s = -%s-\n", $x, $self->$x;
    }
}

package main;

my $m = My::M2->new(a => 'hello', 'b' => 'world');
$m->printtab;
```

Comment: Does package name have to be same as the module name? (I dont think so).

Comment: @Lazer => It does not have to be, but by convention it is.

Comment: @Lazer: No, they don't *technically* have to be the same. However, exports don't work correctly if they're different because, as Eric Strom said, `use Module;` implicitly does `Module->import()` after loading it. If the package in `Module` is named something other than `Module`, then `Module->import()` will be looking at the wrong package and fail to import anything.  If you're not exporting, then there's no reason (other than convention) why the package name and module name would need to be the same.

Answer (score 13):

In Perl, the `use` keyword is exactly equivalent to the following:

```
use Mymodule;

#is the same as

BEGIN {
   require Mymodule;
   Mymodule->import();
}
```

So if you are not defining an import routine in your code (or inheriting from `Exporter`), then your modules are not importing anything into `test.pl`

As Sinan caught, you are not declaring a package in your modules, so they are defaulting to the `main` package.  In that case, all of your subroutines are in `main`, but the lexical variables (declared with `my`) are only scoped to the file they are declared in.

So `m1` defines `sub init` and `sub printab` to which the lexicals `$a` and `$b` are in scope.  But then when `test.pl` loads `m2`, the `init` routine is overwritten with the new definition, which is not closed around the two lexicals anymore.  So it is writing to the package variables `$main::a` and `$main::b` instead of the lexicals which `printab` is bound to.

If you had warnings enabled (which you always should when learning), you would have been warned about the subroutine redefinition.

You should start each of your modules with:

```
package Some::Package::Name;
use warnings;
use strict;
```

and then end each module with:

```
1;
```

This is because when you `use/require` a module, it needs to return a true value at the end so that Perl knows it loaded properly.

Answer (score 2):

`printab()` is defined in the file `m1.pm` and only has access to the `$a` and `$b` variables that are scoped to that file. The variables `$a` and `$b` in `m2.pm` are scoped to that file, and they are *different variables* than the `$a` and `$b` in `m1.pm`.

`init()` sets the variables scoped in `m2.pm` (because that's the last place the `&init` function was defined) so it is not setting the same variables that `printab()` will be trying to print.

Comment: @DVK - No, I meant what I said. Adding a `package Foo` at the top of every file in the OP won't make the lexical variables from one file visible in another file.

Comment: rule - will the scope persist across package boundaries within the same file? E.g. `package A; my $var1 = "x"; 1; package B; print $var1;` - will the `print $var1` see the variable delcared "in" the A package?

Comment: @DVK => a `my` variable is block scoped (where the end of file constitutes an end of block), so in your example, `$var1` is visible in both packages.  When I am using more than one package in a file, I usually enclose the entire package declaration in a block: `{package ...; ....}` so that the lexicals don't leak out

Comment: @Eric - then I stand corrected, it is indeed the file an not the package scope. For some reason I was under impression that a enw package imposes new block scope.

Comment: @DVK: no, you need to explicitly create a new scope around a `package` declaration if you need that.